# Automatically regenerate page content

Tags: asp.net, webforms, browser-cache

I'm in the process of building a site with asp.net web forms, and some of the pages contain graphs. I've found when I'm viewing the local site, sometimes the graphs do not change even when I've changed the code. When I clear my history/cache and reopen the site, the graphs will change to their correct, updated version. Is there any way I can fix this so that every time I reopen the page, it regenerates the graphs (or is this a bad idea)? I'm a little frustrated because when I change the code, I expect the graphs to change the next time I run the site, but about half the time it just pulls up the previous version of the graph. I'm pretty new to asp.net, so maybe there's some automatic setting that I need to change/turn off? The graphs are generated in external javascript, if that's relevant.

Comment: how do you load the data for the graph and where?

Comment: @Legends, I generate the data in the code behind, pass it to the javascript through the .aspx page, and then include the graph in a div element on the page.

Comment: Use chrome dev tools to see what http status code you get back when a request to that page is done.